# How can I output paths with forward slashes with pathlib on Windows?

Tags: python, pathlib

How can I use pathlib to output paths with forward slashes? I often run into programs that accept paths only with forward slashes, but I can't figure out how to make pathlib do that for me.

```py
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath

native = Path('c:/scratch/test.vim')
print(str(native))
# Out: c:\scratch\test.vim
# Backslashes as expected.

posix = PurePosixPath(str(native))
print(str(posix))
# Out: c:\scratch\test.vim
# Why backslashes again?

posix = PurePosixPath('c:/scratch/test.vim')
print(str(posix))
# Out: c:/scratch/test.vim
# Works, but only because I never used a Path object

posix = PurePosixPath(str(native))
print(str(posix).replace('\\', '/'))
# Out: c:/scratch/test.vim
# Works, but ugly and may cause bugs
```

`PurePosixPath` doesn't have `unlink`, `glob`, and other useful utilities in pathlib, so I can't work exclusively with it. `PosixPath` throws NotImplementedError on Windows.

A practical use case where this is necessary: `zipfile.ZipFile` expects forward slashes and fails to match paths when given backslashes.

Is there some way to request a forward-slashed path from pathlib without losing any pathlib functionality?

Comment: Why do you care?  The only place this can cause bugs is if you generate command lines for a batch file.  The cmd shell insists on backslashes.  Every Win32 API will accept either one.

Comment: You could, of course, subclass `Path` and provide your own `__str__` function.

Comment: Just in case, here is another ugly way: `"/".join(native.parts)`. Perhaps a little bit less ugly of buggy. Or not. It depends.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`Path.as_posix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.as_posix) to make the necessary conversion to string with forward slashes.